# issues calling function in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to call a function that catches variables value on call:

**the function:**

```
function check_input_data($INCLUDE_DISABLEDd_types = '', $field1 = '', $field2 = '', $field3 = '', $field4 = '', $field5 = '', $field6 = '', $field7 = '', $field8 = '')
{
    if ( !empty( $INCLUDE_DISABLEDd_types ) )
    {
        global $field1, $field2, $field3, $field4, $field5, $field6, $field7, $field8, $field_1_status, $field_2_status, $field_3_status, $field_4_status, $field_5_status, $field_6_status, $field_7_status, $field_8_status;
        if ( $INCLUDE_DISABLEDd_types == 'email_u' )
        {
            echo "It's noticed the INCLUDE_DISABLEDd var";
            if ( !empty( $field1 ) )
            {
                //I'll tell you what to do later
            }
            if ( !empty( $field2 ) )
            {
                echo $field2;
                if ( preg_match( "/[^-a-z0-9_]/i", $field2 ) )
                {
                    $field_2_status = true;
                    $ff = "good input?";
                }
                else if ( !preg_match( "/[^-a-z0-9_]/i", $field2 ) )
                {
                    $field_2_status = true;
                    $ff = "bad input?";
                }
                else
                {
                    $ff= "something is wrong with preg match";
                }
                echo $ff;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Okay so as you can see, the function will look for only 3 different variables(for now). If it finds them, it will do something.

Now here is the call the the function:

```
check_input_data ('email_u', 'test1', 'LOOK FIELD TWO IS HERE');
```

Now the first var in the function call is for `$included_types` the second for `$field1` and the third for `$field2`.

For some reason, the first var (`$included_types`) which i give a value of `email_u` is detected but the rest (`$field1` and `$field2`) is not.

The reason i know the first var (`$included_types`) is detected is because it echo's out "It's noticed the included var".

As you can see, I've got an if statement to check if `$field2` is empty and if it's not then i tell it to echo the var. Now it doesn't execute any code because it thinks `$field2` is empty (when its not) so i then change the if statement to do the task if it IS empty and it does it but it echos `$field2` with absolutely nothing so i know its not the empty function.

It somehow thinks `$field2` is empty.

I've also tried giving values for ALL vars:

```
check_input_data ('email_u', 'test1', 'LOOK FIELD TWO IS HERE', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test');
```

but it still only picks up the first var, not the rest.

Have I completely mis-understood something? or is there something wrong with the code?

thanks

Comment: Could you not simply pass in your parameters as an array variable, scan the array inside the function and react to the contents of the array?

Comment: You're missing several parenthesis and curly braces which make your code snippet above unusable.

Comment: I've attempted to improve formatting of your code [here](http://pastebin.com/ctmJY0Yw). Try to submit something more along these lines when asking questions! It makes it easier for all of us. As it is, your pasted code contained invalid syntax. Until you resolve that, no one can really say exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: That was an editing mistake, sorry. Fixed now xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the global line and it should work.

Generally it is considered bad practice to use global variables at all, You should instead pass them into the function as parameters (as it seems you have already done).

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!empty($field1
```

Should be

```
if (!empty($field1)) {
```

Cleaned up your code, but I see you already fixed the problem.

```
<?php

function check_input_data($type = '', $field1 = '', $field2 = '') {

    if (!empty($type)) {
        if ($type == 'email_u') {
            if (!empty($field1)) {
                //I'll tell you what to do later
            }

            if (!empty($field2)) {
                echo $field2;

                if (preg_match("/^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/", $field2)) {
                    $field_2_status = TRUE;
                    $ff = "Good input?";
                } else {
                    $field_2_status = FALSE;
                    $ff = "Bad input?";
                }

                echo $ff;
            }
        }   
    }
}

check_input_data('email_u', 'test', 'test');
```

Comment: ooops sorry. that was some editing i did to it. but its correct in the original code, ill edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $field1 and $field from global variabl scope and check the if conditions correctly. if not work post the full code. Then only we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Remove `global $field1, $field2, $field3, $field4, $field5, $field6, $field7, $field8, $field_1_status, $field_2_status, $field_3_status, $field_4_status, $field_5_status, $field_6_status, $field_7_status, $field_8_status;`, make the change @John Svensson posted if it wasn't a typo and add a closing brace (`}`) for the function.

Comment: I don't need to remove $field_1_status, $field_2_status, $field_3_status etc (Do i?) as i will be defining them inside the function later on. So it should be okay to keep them but get rid of $field1,2,3 vars, right?

Comment: If you're only going to be using those variables _inside_ that function, there's no need to set them as global. If you use / set them outside the function though, then yes, you could set them as global within the function to work with them in it.

Comment: I'll be setting them inside the function, but using them outside.